# Hydrogeology Aquifer Question - Estimating Freshwater Availability

Tags: geology, hydrology

*Bikini Atoll is at the northern end of the Ralik chain, and in a region that is somewhat drier.  On average, the Atoll receives 1300 mm of rainfall each year, with the wettest season being from May through November.  Total annual evapotranspiration is 1040 mm, with the remained being recharge.
Aquifers*

*The islands are composed of calcium carbonate sands over consolidated reef rock (calcium carbonate).

Look at bikini island. The sands comprise the primary aquifer on the island.  They have an average hydraulic conductivity of 5 × 10<sup>-3</sup> cm/sec.  Sands extend to approximately 5 meters below sea level.  Porosity of the sands is 30%.  The reef rock has a lower hydraulic conductivity of 8 × 10<sup>-5</sup> cm/sec, and can only be considered a secondary source due to unreliable yields.*

*Assume the density of seawater is 1.025 g/cm<sup>3</sup> and freshwater is 1.000 g/cm<sup>3</sup> .*

*Mission:*

***Calculate the volume of available water for Bikini Island.  You can model it as an infinite strip, but need to take care near the ends of the island.***

Use Google Earth to make measurements.

I made some measurements of Bikini Island: ~3700 m long and 850 m wide. I think I'm supposed to use Darcy's Law and make multiple measurements from the center of the island but I'm not really sure what to do with that. Any pointers would help.